# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:

Tags: java, input, knapsack-problem

I am working on the knapsack problem, I am new to Java. I am able to add numbers manually like this in the main:

```
 // Fill the bag of weights. 
 //myWeights.bagOfWeights.add(18);
 //myWeights.bagOfWeights.add(2);
 //System.out.println("Possible answers: ");
 //myWeights.fillKnapSack(20);
```

However, I am not able to allow the user to input the numbers. 
The first number should be the target followed by the weights. 
So I have tried to take the user input as a string and split it up with whitespace, and then convert it to an integer.
 Next, I tried to do the parseInt 2 ways, but I was unsuccessful both way.
 Here is the code:

```html
import java.util.*;
 
  public class KnapSackWeights{
 
    private Sack bagOfWeights = new Sack();
    private Sack knapSack = new Sack();
 
    public static void main(String[] args){
        KnapSackWeights myWeights = new KnapSackWeights();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the input:");
        String input = in.nextLine();
        String[] sar = input.split(" ");
        //System.out.println(inp);
        int target = Integer.parseInt(input);
        System.out.println(target);
        
        int[] weights_array = new int[26];
        
        int n = input.length()-1;
        for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
        {
           weights_array[i - 1] = Integer.parseInt(sar[i]);
        }
        int k = weights_array[0];
        myWeights.bagOfWeights.add(target);
        //System.out.println(target);
        System.out.println("Possible answers: ");
        myWeights.fillKnapSack(k);
        //myWeights.fillKnapSack(Integer.parseInt(sar[0]));

        // Fill the bag of weights. 
        //myWeights.bagOfWeights.add(11);
        //myWeights.bagOfWeights.add(8);
        //myWeights.bagOfWeights.add(7);
        //myWeights.bagOfWeights.add(6);
        //myWeights.bagOfWeights.add(5);
        //myWeights.bagOfWeights.add(4);
        
        //System.out.println("Possible answers: ");
        //myWeights.fillKnapSack(20);
    }
```

Here is the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input
>   string: "18 7 4 6"    at
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)     at
>   java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)  at
>   KnapSackWeights.main(KnapSackWeights.java:18)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are splitting the ``input`` in ``String[] sar`` but you are not even using it.  You end up parsing the line, of course ``Integer`` can't parse such a string with spaces.

Comment: @SchiduLuca Is there a way to fix this? The conversion from String to integer, does not work properly. So if I dont parse the string with spaces, that should resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `parseInt` method with the String `18 7 4 6`. Since this isn't a valid Integer, the NumberFormatException is thrown.

You are already splitting the input into the `String[] sar`. In the `for` loop you already call `parseInt` on each value in `sar`, which are valid Integers. Seems like you have everything in place; just remove the `int target = Integer.parseInt(input);` line.

Comment: If I remove the target, what can I add to myWeights.bagOfWeights.add(target); for it to add the content?

Comment: @user8581463 It depends; what do you want to put in there? Right now `.add(target);` doesn't get reached because of the exception, and if it did get reached it wouldn't do you any good, because `target` _is not a valid int anyway_. I assume the int you want to put in there is in the `sar` array, so you get it from there.

Comment: Inserting the sar array also leaves me with an error: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4 for the line weights_array[i - 1] = Integer.parseInt(sar[i]);

Comment: @user8581463 That is caused by running the loop as many times as the length of "18 7 4 6", which is 8, and `sar` only has index 0-3. This is, however, totally unrelated to the question, and pretty easy to solve by googling.

Comment: I have tried googling for the past hour trying to figure out why the index is out of bounds, but I cannot see why. I am not trying to access an illegal index, nor is the index a negative nor is it greater than the size of the array. The first number is not the length, it is just the target. Also, I don't understand what I am missing, because I think the code is clearly trying to access the length of the user input and use that length for the for loop

Answer (score -1):

maybe this could be helpful

```
        //your input
        String input = "18 7 4 6";
        //split into string array by space
        String[] split = input.split(" ");
        int[] nums = new int[split.length];
        //parse each string into number
        for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
            nums[i] = Integer.parseInt(split[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));
```