# I cannot read a big CSV file with krangl, but I can read a small one

Tags: dataframe, csv, kotlin

I am just starting with Kotlin and IntelliJ Idea. Making some progress, with the help of people at SO. But now I am stuck again. The following program runs flawlessly:

```
import krangl.*

val dataPath = "C:\\Users\\fsald\\Dropbox\\Temp\\AAPL.CSV"
val dataPath1 = "C:\\Users\\fsald\\Dropbox\\Code\\Julia\\IOFiles\\Input\\AllData.CSV"

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    krangl.irisData.print()

    val data = krangl.DataFrame.readCSV(dataPath)
    data.print()
}
```

I mean the two dataframes `irisData` and `data` are printed correctly on the screen (omitted).

However, if I add (just before the final curly bracket) a single line that attempts to read a large CSV file (about 600 columns and 25000 rows) the program crashes. The additional line and the error messages are here:

```
val data1 = krangl.DataFrame.readCSV(dataPath1)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: invalid boolean cell value
    at krangl.TableIOKt.cellValueAsBoolean(TableIO.kt:336)
    at krangl.TableIOKt.dataColFactory(TableIO.kt:372)
    at krangl.TableIOKt.dataColFactory(TableIO.kt:376)
    at krangl.TableIOKt.readDelim(TableIO.kt:175)
    at krangl.TableIOKt.readDelim$default(TableIO.kt:133)
    at krangl.TableIOKt.readDelim(TableIO.kt:129)
    at krangl.TableIOKt.readCSV(TableIO.kt:43)
    at krangl.TableIOKt.readCSV$default(TableIO.kt:39)
    at MainKt.main(Main.kt:12)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any ideas on the reason for this?

Comment: reading is not issue some data facing the issuehttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/46688113/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-numberformatexception-for-input-string

Comment: Just a comment, since I am not familiar with krangl in particular, but: The exception says that krangl tried to interpret the data as a boolean (true/false) value, but the data was suddenly something else (not "true" or "false"). I guess that the first row contains a value in that column that leads krangl to believe that it's a boolean when it actually shouldn't. Maybe have a look at how your CSV data looks like in a text editor and check if there is any way how you can manually tell krangl the data types. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Just a small note that Krangl is no longer being developed in favor of [Kotlin DataFrame](https://github.com/Kotlin/dataframe).